# How to determine the size in memory of a standard library string or other non-fundamental datatype in C++?

Tags: c++, memory

How can I determine the in-memory size of a non-fundamental C++ type (such as string, vector, multimap, etc)?

I know I can get the theoretical 'starting' size using sizeof:

```
string test = "thisisatest";  // sizeof returns 28
string test2 = "thisisareallylongtestdearlordthisstringisclearlymorethan28bytesandisarunonsentenceaintnobodygonnabreakamystride"; // sizeof returns 28
```

But how can I see how much memory test2 (and not the string type) uses in bytes?

Comment: You can't programmatically.  You'd need to look at the implementation code, and figure it out from there.

Comment: @Kamiccolo: Not the same problem; here the OP wishes to know the memory including the dynamic allocation performed by `std::string`.

Comment: @Kamiccolo Thanks, but it is not the same question.  I'm asking how to find out how much memory is actually used by an object in memory; the question you referenced is the theoretical size and not the actual size.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth Thanks Oli -- So I'm pretty much either going to have to figure it out myself or utilize the type's built in size function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to know how your used class is implemented. `sizeof(obj)` only returns the in memory size of the object itself, but not the memory usage on heap for allocated data. std::string allocates memory for the data of the string itself. And the implementation is free to implement it any kind. Maybe std::string allocates 1k of memory only for a single byte to make it faster for further operations.

The only way to get the total amount of actually required memory is to look inside the used implementation and sum up all allocated memory and the sizeof the class itself.

Answer (score 1):

In C++11 you can exploit the fact that allocators can have a state. This solution is implementation-independent.

```
template<class T>
struct myalloc : std::allocator<T>
{
   using pointer = typename std::allocator<T>::pointer;
   using const_pointer = typename std::allocator<T>::const_pointer;
   using size_type = typename std::allocator<T>::size_type;

   pointer allocate( size_type n, std::allocator<void>::const_pointer hint = 0 )
   {
    if (counter)
      (*counter)+= sizeof(T)*n;
    return std::allocator<T>::allocate( n, hint );
   }

   void deallocate( pointer p, size_type n )
   {
    if (counter)
      (*counter)-= sizeof(T)*n;
    return std::allocator<T>::deallocate( p, n );
   }

   template< class U > struct rebind { typedef myalloc<U> other; };

   typedef std::true_type propagate_on_container_copy_assignment;
   typedef std::true_type propagate_on_container_move_assignment;
   typedef std::true_type propagate_on_container_swap;


   myalloc( int * p = 0 ) : counter(p) {}
   int * counter;
};

typedef std::basic_string< char, std::char_traits<char>, myalloc<char> > mystring;
```

And you can use it like this:

```
int main()
{
  int cnt = sizeof( mystring );
  mystring c ("hello, world!", custom_alloc<char>(&cnt) );

  cout << cnt << endl; // result is implementation dependent
  return 0;
}
```